# Unparsable Date Exception : SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

am getting date as string

```
String dateStr = Mon Mar 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

but am getting unparsable date exception when am tring to parse using SimpleDateFormat

```
java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateStr);
```

please help me to solve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "GMT" part is confusing things - the `Z` format specifier expects just "0800" or similar.

You can change your format to:

```
"EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z"
```

and that will work. (It's ignoring the time zone name at the end of the string, of course.)

Comment: Failed to see your answer. My thoughts were exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

This'll work:

```
java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String dateStr = "Mon Mar 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
        
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                .appendPattern("EEE MMM d u H:m:s")
                                .appendLiteral(' ')
                                .appendZoneId()
                                .appendPattern("X")
                                .appendLiteral(" (")
                                .appendZoneText(TextStyle.FULL)
                                .appendLiteral(')')
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, dtf);
        
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-03-31T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
```

For any reason, if you need an object of `java.util.Date` from this object of `ZonedDateTime`, you can so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>